# how to assign value to EIP with C language in ubuntu

Tags: c, linux

where is wrong? how to assign value to eip to change the location of running in program?

Please help !!!!

error: cannot convert ‘mcontext_t*’ to ‘sigcontext*’ in assignment

```
struct ucontext {
    unsigned long     uc_flags;
    struct ucontext  *uc_link;
    stack_t       uc_stack;
    struct sigcontext uc_mcontext;
    sigset_t      uc_sigmask;   /* mask last for extensibility */
};

#include <stdio.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <asm/ucontext.h>
void handler(int signum, siginfo_t *siginfo, void *uc0){
    struct ucontext *uc;
    struct sigcontext *sc;

    uc = (struct ucontext *)uc0;
    sc = &uc->uc_mcontext;

    sc->eip = target;
    //uc->uc_mcontext.gregs[REG_EIP]
}

int main (int argc, char** argv){
    struct sigaction act;
    act.sa_sigaction = handler;
    act.sa_flags = SA_SIGINFO;
    sigaction(SIGTRAP, &act, NULL);

    asm("movl $skipped, %0" : : "m" (target));

    asm("int3"); // cause SIGTRAP
    printf("to be skipped.\n");
    asm("skipped:");
    printf("Done.\n");
}
```

Comment: For a start, you need to move your `#includes` so that they are before `struct ucontext`, otherwise `sigset_t` *et al* will not be defined before they are used.

Comment: It compiles and runs on my PC without error. GCC 4.3

Comment: gcc (Ubuntu 4.4.1-4ubuntu9) 4.4.1 running is wrong

Comment: ucontext_t *context = (ucontext_t*)arg;

context->uc_mcontext.gregs[REG_RIP] = ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just fyi. Check the `man setjmp` and `man longjmp`.